# Filter items from a drop-down list

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In an HTML table, I have a dropdown list on the right, which is called type, there are two items (`in` and `out`).

[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCCIh.png)

My goal is to filter the items: If I select from my `IN` dropdown, I should see all the items in the HTML here is an example.

[img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoHmH.png)

My problem is that when I choose an item from my list. For example `IN`, HTML table data does not filter. Unfortunately, I don't get any error message...

I tried to debug:

```
public selectedBrand: any; 
public onChangeType(type:any) {
    console.log("Begin ");
    
    this.selectedBrand=type;
        this.filteredCustomer=this.customerTransferts.filter(
          (item) => item.type === this.selectedBrand
        );
        console.log("Data");
        console.log(this.filteredCustomer);     
}
```

I don't have any error

[img3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZylEJ.png)

I have the impression that there is a problem in the HTML?

```
<select class="form-select" style="max-width: 100px" [ngModel]="selectedBrand" (ngModelChange)="onChangeType($event)">
   <option [value]="'IN'">IN</option>
   <option [value]="'OUT'">OUT</option>
</select>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you using reactjs, angular or vanilla javascript?

Comment: @blaze-centurion: I am on Angular, thanks

Comment: In that case, I can't help you as I am not familiar with angular. Sorry!